# Converting codes from Javascript to Python

Tags: javascript, python

I have few codes in Javascript that I want to convert in Python

First JS

```
if (var1.charCodeAt(var2) % 2) var3 = 1;
```

Python code

```
if (ord(var1[var2])) % 2):
var3 = 1:
```

JS

```
var4.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(var5.substr(var1, 2), 36) - var3));
```

Python

```
var4.append(chr(int(var5[var1: 2], 36) - var3))
```

JS

```
    for (var1 = 0; var1 < var2.length; var1 += 2) {
```

Python

```
var1 = 0
while (var1 < len(arr1)):
    var1+= 2
```

Could someone correct me here please. Not quite getting the codes clearly.

Comment: Missing the `:` after the if statement and the newline in the first python example.

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Comment: That's a mess.. you should have a little read about [python syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_syntax.htm)

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful..I know about syntax...this is just a quick draft which i have not implied withing the program yet. All I was asking is the converted codes..If you guys think that I should be perfect then I wasn't gonna ask your help at the first place.

Comment: Nope, we didn't expect you to be perfect. But we do expect you to try some research before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake:

```
if (ord(var1[var2])) % 2: #too much parentheses, fixed.
    var3 = 1 #: <- What's this? Also, mind your indentation.
```

Also, about the last one:

```
var1 = 0
while (var1 < len(arr1)): 
    var1+= 2
```

That's fine, congratulations. But i would prefer to do it this way:

```
for var1 in range(0, len(arr1), 2):
    #do something
```

That should do it.

**Edit**
Turns out there isn't really that much mistakes. About the second one, the `36` is the base number of the string to be converted.

Comment: What's the purpose of that "36" there? I can't figure that part out..that's the main issue I was having..rest was going to be figured out eventually...Thanks for correction.

Comment: Are you saying this isn't your script?

Comment: No its a script from a random site. I don't have any clue in JS. That's why trying to understand the code

Answer (score 1):

The third snippet can be converted as follows:

```
for var1 in range(0, len(arr1), 2):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your indices... charAt function in Javascript seems to be 1-based, while Python treat strings as arrays, so it's always 0-based.

For instance: `var1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; var2 = 13`.

JS `var1.charAt(var2)` yields `'n'`, while Python `var[var2]` yields `'o'`.

Also, review how string slicing differs to one another. JS `substr` takes start and length as arguments, but Python works with start and end positions.